# kivy floating button android material design style

Tags: android, kivy, kivy-language

Is there any way I could implement a button floating on top all other things. For example, the Reddit android app has such a button. I don't want to use kivymd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just put your content in a FloatLayout for example, and the button as another child of the FloatLayout, and tell it to be the desired size and position.

```
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: '1'
        Label:
            text: '2'
        Label:
            text: '3'
        Label:
            text: '4'


    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        right: self.width and root.right - 200
        y: 200
        text: 'such button'
```

Comment: But, how does kivy know which one of the elements in the float layout is above the other? Are widgets placed in the float layout one after another, so in your case first the BoxLayout is placed and afterwards possibly on top the Button?

Comment: widgets are displayed on top of each others, in the order they are added to the parent (which in kv is the order of writting), some layout (like BoxLayout) prevents children to be on top of each others, FloatLayout does not.